# Flagging an id based on another column has different values in R

Tags: r, flags

I have a flagging rule need to apply.

Here is how my dataset looks like:

```
    df <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,1, 2,2,2,2, 3,3,3,3),
                 key = c("a","a","b","c", "a","b","c","d", "a","b","c","c"),
                 form = c("A","B","A","A", "A","A","A","A", "B","B","B","A"))
    
    > df
   id key form
1   1   a    A
2   1   a    B
3   1   b    A
4   1   c    A
5   2   a    A
6   2   b    A
7   2   c    A
8   2   d    A
9   3   a    B
10  3   b    B
11  3   c    B
12  3   c    A
```

I would like to flag `id`s based on a `key` columns that has duplicates, a third column of `form` shows different forms for each `key`. The idea is to understand if an id has taken any items from multiple forms. I need to add a filtering column as below:

```
> df.1
   id key form type
1   1   a    A multiple
2   1   a    B multiple
3   1   b    A multiple 
4   1   c    A multiple
5   2   a    A single
6   2   b    A single
7   2   c    A single
8   2   d    A single
9   3   a    B multiple
10  3   b    B multiple
11  3   c    B multiple
12  3   c    A multiple
```

And eventually I need to get rid off the extra duplicated row which has different `form`. To decide which of the duplicated one drops, I pick whichever the `form` type has more items.

In a final separate dataset, I would like to have something like below:

```
  > df.2
       id key form type
    1   1   a    A multiple
    3   1   b    A multiple 
    4   1   c    A multiple
    5   2   a    A single
    6   2   b    A single
    7   2   c    A single
    8   2   d    A single
    9   3   a    B multiple
    10  3   b    B multiple
    11  3   c    B multiple
```

So first `id` has `form A` dominant so kept the `A`, and the third `id` has `form B` dominant so kept the `B`.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can check number of distinct elements to create the new column by group and then `filter` based on the highest frequency (`Mode`)

```
library(dplyr)
df.2 <- df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(type = if(n_distinct(form) > 1) 'multiple' else 'single') %>% 
  filter(form == Mode(form)) %>%
  ungroup
```

-output

```
> df.2
# A tibble: 10 × 4
      id key   form  type    
   <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr>   
 1     1 a     A     multiple
 2     1 b     A     multiple
 3     1 c     A     multiple
 4     2 a     A     single  
 5     2 b     A     single  
 6     2 c     A     single  
 7     2 d     A     single  
 8     3 a     B     multiple
 9     3 b     B     multiple
10     3 c     B     multiple
```

where

```
Mode <- function(x) {
  ux <- unique(x)
  ux[which.max(tabulate(match(x, ux)))]
}
```

Comment: This answers my question perfectly! thanks for your time!